# Attempt to read or write file outside of disk 'hd0'. You need to load the kernel first

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have a dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.3.

```
error: attempt to read or write file outside of disk 'hd0'
error: you need to load the kernel first.
Press enter any key to continue...
```

Entering any key would take me back to grub menu and again if I selected Ubuntu it would freeze in a blank screen. Select Windows won't even boot. Blank screen again. Before this, every time boot would result in grub rescue mode.

`grub rescue> ls`.
Nothing shows up.

I knew Ubuntu partition is in `/dev/sda8`. So I set prefix to `(hd0,8)/boot/grub` and set root to (hd0,8). Done insmod normal.

Since then, I'm stuck with the error in the question.

Sorry for the editing. I'm typing this from a phone.

Edit: It is back to 'no such partition' 'Entering rescue mode' now. Grub menu no longer shows up.

Comment: I've seen what you describe before, and it was on a failing (very close to dead hdd).  I'd stop trying to use your hdd, boot a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media) and check your hdd/sdd's health from it's electronics (ie. SMART).  The easiest tool is `gnome-disks`, but `smartctl` provides more information (too much possibly).  I suspect your disk is dead or dying & whatever life you have left should be used to grab needed files from it; checking SMART data reads health from circuitry so won't use any remaining life...

Comment: Checked disk health from 'disks' in Ubuntu. It read 'Disk is likely to fail soon'. So yes, disk is failing. But this problem has to be resolved. The very second Ubuntu boots normally, I'll back everything up.

Comment: I wouldn't try and boot it (a / mount, esp. with swap if on device, will put a lot of stress on it).  Even without swap active, you can't afford to use it's remaining health to load programs to explore/copy/...  I'd use a 'live' system (with `swapoff` so it's not stressing disk either!) mount & copy your important files first, then slowly less-important files.  I'd be tempted to script it so you're using the drive as little as possible; but it's your drive, and you know what data is important, what data you already have backed up etc...

Comment: It's a 500 GB HDD and about 300 gigs of data is important. I can only upload them to cloud.

Comment: The errors in your question imply you already have problems with your 'boot' part of your drive.. Fixing it will require a lot of diagnostics time, and what will likely be a huge % of whatever life the drive has left.  It is my opinion it's too risky & bound to fail (loss of all your data).  Whatever configuration you need to enable your cloud via a 'live' system can be done before you `mount` your hdd/sdd, thus won't impact it's health, after `mount` you quickly `cp`|`scp` (or run your backup script to save) your data to your desired backup place increasing the chance of saving more data...

Comment: Only once your data is safely backed up, do you try and let diagnostics run, repair the damage (which can cause it to get worse as we know the boot area is bad already), and work out if the drive is salvageable and capable of getting back to being able to boot again. The diagnostics will take a long time (depending on type & quality of drive) & there is a reasonable/good chance it'll likely cause it's failure.  Your data with luck is hopefully in a good part of the disk, so you try & get this off safely first!

Comment: Alright. Will do that. Thanks mate.